# Why are local ports being opened outside of the Dynamic Port Range?

Tags: windows, port

Ran the following command on a Windows client machine.

```
> netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp

 Protocol tcp Dynamic Port Range
 ---------------------------------
 Start Port      : 49152
 Number of Ports : 16384
```

Based on the above output, one would expect opened ports to be between 49,152 and 65,536, but with an application running, the nestat command returns the following (ip address was changed for obvious reasons) :

```
  TCP    111.111.11.11:22416    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    111.111.11.11:22436    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    111.111.11.11:22448    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    111.111.11.11:22485    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    111.111.11.11:22498    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    111.111.11.11:22514    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    111.111.11.11:22516    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    111.111.11.11:22518    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    111.111.11.11:22522    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    111.111.11.11:22526    myServer:8888           CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    111.111.11.11:22538    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    111.111.11.11:22584    myServer:8888           CLOSE_WAIT
```

Ran the same command on another Windows client machine.

```
 > netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp

 Protocol tcp Dynamic Port Range
 ---------------------------------
 Start Port      : 49152
 Number of Ports : 16384
```

This generates a range of ports as expected between 49,152 and 65,536.

```
  TCP    222.222.22.22:51131    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    222.222.22.22:51348    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    222.222.22.22:51362    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    222.222.22.22:51363    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    222.222.22.22:51364    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    222.222.22.22:51356    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    222.222.22.22:51382    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    222.222.22.22:51385    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    222.222.22.22:51386    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    222.222.22.22:51387    myServer:8888           CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    222.222.22.22:51392    myServer:8888           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    222.222.22.22:51398    myServer:8888           CLOSE_WAIT
```

**Questions:**

What would cause a Window client to select a range of ports outside the expected range?

Any settings to check, commands to run, or registry entries to verify?

Comment: That might depend on the software that is opening these ports. You may use tcpview for that.

Comment: If the software (Java making url.connect() call), just makes a call, isn't it the OS doing the actual opening of the ports? Is it possible to set port limits per user or per process on the Windows client machine?

Comment: Using a test program that makes numerous connection, tcpview doesn't show me anything different yet netstat shows me numerous ports being accessed. Granted I haven't used tcpview much, but did ensure all the Connection States are checked.